# Cyclic trace of Grassmannian matrices

Tags: matrices, trace, grassmannian

We know trace of matrix satisfies $$
\text{tr}(ABCD)= \text{tr}(DABC)
$$
if the matrices are taking values on usually numbers.

Assume now the Matrices are Grassmannian valued, or they are fermions.
By this, I mean a fermion taking values in color group such as SU(N).
Then my question is:  is it true that
$$
\text{tr}(\psi_1\psi_2\psi_3\psi_4) = - \text{tr}(\psi_4\psi_1\psi_2\psi_3)
$$
where the minus sign is due to anticommutate $\psi_4$ three times.

I prove it like this.
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{tr}(\psi_1\psi_2\psi_3\psi_4) &=& (\psi_1)^i_j  (\psi_2)^j_k  (\psi_3)^k_l  (\psi_4)^l_i \\
&=& - (\psi_1)^i_j  (\psi_2)^j_k (\psi_4)^l_i (\psi_3)^k_l   \\
&=&  (\psi_1)^i_j (\psi_4)^l_i (\psi_2)^j_k  (\psi_3)^k_l   \\
&=& - (\psi_4)^l_i (\psi_1)^i_j  (\psi_2)^j_k  (\psi_3)^k_l \\
&=& - \text{tr}(\psi_4\psi_1\psi_2\psi_3)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: "Matrices are Grassmannian valued or are fermions": could you give at least a reference ?

Comment: In my mind I am considering fermions which take values in SU(N) or SO(N) color group. Thanks for pointing this out. I have clarified this point. This exists in 2+1 dimensional conformal field theory or 3+1 dimensional superconformal field theory

Comment: @JeanMarie Surely tiyan Li means the entries of the matrix come from an anticommutative ring, where $\psi_1 \psi_2 = -\psi_2 \psi_1$. This happens if the entries live in an exterior algebra and multiplication is the wedge product. The question could certainly be more clearly written, especially for mathematicians. In any case, the argument looks fine to me.

Comment: @Joshua P. Swanson Thanks. Very enlightning explanation.